# Quick launch tool bar

Tags: windows-vista, quicklaunch

I want to increase the number of icons in the quick launch bar from  3 (hope its the default), is there any way i can increase the number to display more number of icons on the bar instead of pressing the double arrow keys and then selecting the icon in windows vista

Answer (score 5):

Taken from: http://www.technobuzz.net/expand-the-quick-launch-area-in-vista-task-bar/

To unlock taskbar: Right click taskbar and uncheck "Lock the Taskbar"

> 1. Unlock the Windows Vista Taskbar.
> 2. Move the pointer on top of the dots displayed between the Quick Launch icons. The arrow will change to a double-arrow.
> 3. Click with your left mouse button and keep the button held down. Now, move your mouse to the right to increase the size provided to the Quick Launch toolbar, or to the left to decrease it.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the QuickLaunch toolbar, de-select "Lock the toolbar", then you can resize the toolbar to your desired width.  Optionally, you can then re-lock the toolbar.

EDIT: Just noticed that you said Vista, so I can't be certain this is the same in Vista as it is in XP.